# Adding query param to mailchimp request with Node.js client library

Tags: node.js, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to list out all my interests from the MailChimp api using the @mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing npm library, as that is what they use as examples for node.js in their docs.

Link to the npm library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing

Link to the relevant documentation for this specific endpoint: https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/interests/list-interests-in-category/

Now, I can get my interests just fine with the example code there:

```
const run = async () => {
  const response = await client.lists.listInterestCategoryInterests(
    "list_id",
    "interest_category_id"
  );
  console.log(response);
};

run();
```

The problem is, that by default the MailChimp API only returns the first 10 items in the list, and I need 15. There is an easy way to change this, of course, by adding a query param `count=15`. However, I can't find any way to pass on a query param with the `listInterestCategoryInterests` method as provided through the official library.

!TL;DR! So my question is:
Does anybody know how to pass on query params to the mailchimp API through the official node.js npm library, or do I really have to resort to just dropping the library entirely as it does not provide this basic functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list params as a string in an  array:

```
const response = await client.lists.listInterestCategoryInterests({fields:[    "list_id,interest_category_id"]}
  );
```

**NOTE**: A prefix maybe required as per below:

```
const response = await mailchimp.reports.getAllCampaignReports({fields:["reports.campaign_title,reports.clicks"]})
```

Result:

```
[0] {
[0]   reports: [
[0]     { campaign_title: 'COACT EMAIL CAMPAIGN', clicks: [Object] },
[0]     { campaign_title: '', clicks: [Object] }
[0]   ]
[0] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const response = await mailchimp.lists.getListMembersInfo(listId,
                {
                    count: 1000
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone coming here hoping to learn how to pass QUERY params into mailchimp marketing library methods:

The query parameters are taken from `opts` object - the object properties have to be camelCase.

In terms of which parameter for the method the `opts` object is - it depends on the method and you might need to check the method's source code, but probably second or third parameter.

As for the question for the concrete method, this should be the solution:

```
await client.lists.listInterestCategoryInterests(
    "list_id",
    "interest_category_id",
    { count: 15 }
  );
```