# Nodejs mailchimp marketing api ignores my query parameters

Tags: node.js, mailchimp, query-string, mailchimp-api-v3.0

**My problem**
I want to get a list of members through the Mailchimp marketing API in Nodejs. I am using the [mailchimp_marketing npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing).

**What I tried**
For example I want to only get the VIPs in my Mailchimp list. Following their [API reference](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/list-members-info/) and this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64140581/13664713) I tried this:

```js
const members = await mailchimpClient.lists.getListMembersInfo(`${list_id}`, {
    vip_only: true
});
```

But the response gives also members who aren't VIPs, so it totally ignores the query parameter.
I also tried other parameters like *since_timestamp_opt*, *before_last_changed* , etc. But those get ignored aswell.
For some way only `count=1000` works fine.

I also tried other ways like:

```js
const members = await mailchimpClient.lists.getListMembersInfo("f8b3bf6b23?vip_only=true");
const members = await mailchimpClient.lists.getListMembersInfo("f8b3bf6b23/members?vip_only=true");
```

But does not give the expected result.

Anyone knows what the right way is to pass the parameters? Or should I just do it client-side?

Answer (score 1):

I know that is too late, but here is the answer for the future. I was stuck by the same problem. I checked the source code and the problem is unbelievable.

The query params must be in cameCase, not in underscore like the documentation, I added an image example.

So, instead of using "vip_only", you need use "vipOnly"

[image: Source code of Mailchimp Marketing api]

Comment: Unbelievable indeed. Well, thanks for finding this out!

Answer (score 1):

CTO of Mailchimp here - sorry about this issue, it was indeed not as you'd expect. We just patched this so it will work with snake_case format as described in the API, but also continue working for anyone who'd already coded it with camelCase before. Sorry about the confusion and effort this caused for anyone.

For completeness, here's the patch that fixes it in the code generator:
https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-client-lib-codegen/commit/7356f8e445e571824e8c1f463f11d246d1f6f797

and here's the commit that fixes it in all the proper places in the SDK library:
https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-node/commit/6f269cc06ef99ad2cc1597e822cfc0da6797fae7